# What are chat events and how do they work?

Tags: support, faq-proposed, chat-event

In spite of being an active user for 3 years on Stack Exchange, I don't know anything about chat events. Probably because communities I used to be active in might not (or rarely) take part in chat events.

After searching on here, I didn't find any existing post that provides details about chat events.

Before starting an event for my community (Hinduism.SE), or taking part in chat events, I would like to ask the question here:

- What are the chat events and how do they work?

Provide comprehensive details regarding things related to chat events like:

- What is this? Who can start?
- Who & how can one take part in?
- In brief, how does it work?

Comment: For [scifi.se]: [What is a Movie Night, really?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7431/70236) We periodically hold film/TV nights, the latest being [a _Star Trek: TNG_ night](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10846/70236), and the upcoming one being a [_Nausicaa from the Valley of the Wind_](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10879/70236) night.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A chat event is an invitation for regulars and passersby of a chat room to have a focused chat around a topic. The event is used to both announce the start date and time as well the duration.

Any room owner of a chat room can create an event on the [Schedule](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/1034/shadows-sandbox?tab=schedule) tab of the room:

[image: schedule an event]

Once you clicked Add the event is added to the Room Schedule, a [message](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6023890#6023890) is posted in the room and the event is featured on the Main Chat page:

[image: Chat events]

From that moment on users can register themselves for the event. There is no restriction on who can register. Any logged in user can register for the event, by clicking the *Register yourself* button next to the event. After a while you'll see for example this for the [Happy hour](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/89/tavern-on-the-meta?tab=schedule) in the Tavern on the Meta:

[image: scheduled meeting]

Users that have registered will receive an inbox notification and [email reminder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqHhB.png) (when [enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAD3o.png)) about two hours before the start of the event. Shortly (6 to 8 minutes) before the start of the event every user that is pingable in the room will see a  chat popup that the event is about to start.

[image: start event popup]

Depending on the type of *event* there can be a formal start, for example by the chair of an event. In the [SOCVR room meeting](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/35132973#35132973) events we follow a pre-determined agenda and the meeting is chaired by one of the Room Owners. But the Happy hour on the other hand either happens or it doesn't. It highly depends on who shows up.

There is no notification or visible reminder when an event is about to end. On the Schedule tab of the room you'll see the text *currently running* and  how much time is remaining for the event.

As explained earlier anyone can subscribe for the event and there is nothing special happening in the room settings due to an event being ongoing, anyone can join the room, anyone can talk, registered for the event or not (assuming the room is not in gallery mode). If you want to restrict your audience either create a gallery room specific for the event and then only grant write access to those users that have registered. As an alternative have a room owner kick users out of the room after a warning that you feel disturb the event ...

As there is no guidance on what an event should be or what it should look like it is hard to give an explicit set of rules to follow. For kind of formal meetings rooms can formulate their own guidance like [SOCVR](https://socvr.org/room-info/room-meetings/room-meetings) did. That guidance is closely related to what the [Python](http://sopython.com/wiki/sopython_Meeting_Transcripts) room does.

Other rooms have regular events, like [The Physics room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/71/the-h-bar?tab=schedule) that *just happen*.

Each room, its roomowners and regulars are free to suggest events, have them scheduled by an room owner and decide about its form, topic, length and recurrence.