# We have meetups, events, community-events, conferences tags. Are all the same?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We have three tags that together have 39 questions:

- [events](/questions/tagged/events) 22 questions, 0 watchers, no tag excerpt, no tag wiki
- [meetups](/questions/tagged/meetups) 14 questions, 0 watchers, tag excerpt and tag wiki
- [community-events](/questions/tagged/community-events) 3 questions, 0 watchers, no tag excerpt, no tag wiki
- [conferences](/questions/tagged/conferences) 3 questions, 0 watchers, no tag excerpt, no tag wiki

Should we burninate [community-events](/questions/tagged/community-events) as it only has 3 questions or should we make it a synonym of [meetups](/questions/tagged/meetups)?

On the other hand, should [conferences](/questions/tagged/conferences) and [events](/questions/tagged/events) be synonyms of [meetups](/questions/tagged/meetups) or there are other relevant kinds of conferences and events around the Stack Exchange Network to discuss on this site?

Answer (score 3):

Community events are items that show up in the "community bulletin" section of the front page.  Sites use these to announce everything from upcoming space launches (Space) to new blog posts (SciFi, Worldbuilding, maybe others).  They have nothing to do with people getting together.  I just added a wiki excerpt for [community-events](/questions/tagged/community-events).

The "events" tag has a mix of questions (some probably mistagged).  Some of them ask about [chat events](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295936/162102), which are like scheduled "meetings" in chat rooms.  These, too, are not about offline activity.

"Meetups" seems to be about offline gatherings.

All three tags are relevant, though "events" should be reviewed.  If all the questions that should have this tag (a subset of the ones that do) are about chat events, the tag should be renamed [chat-events](/questions/tagged/chat-events) for clarity. (Update: apparently there is a [chat-event](/questions/tagged/chat-event) tag already, so we can retag these.)

[conferences](/questions/tagged/conferences) has three questions, two of which are about specific conferences that happened in the past.  I suggest retagging these with [meetups](/questions/tagged/meetups).

Comment: @Rubén updated.  I think those three questions should be retagged with meetups instead.

Comment: Thank you. I'll wait a bit before proceeding by my-self to do that change. In the mean time I'll review [tag:chat] [tag:events] to add [tag:chat-event] if appropriate  (just found that [tag:chat-event] already exists)

Answer (score 1):

Following the [Monica's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316790/289691), specifically the statement regarding [events](/questions/tagged/events) has a mix of questions, I think that those questions about

- **chat events**, specially on those having [chat](/questions/tagged/chat) and [events](/questions/tagged/events), [events](/questions/tagged/events) should be replaced by [chat-event](/questions/tagged/chat-event)
- "events" that refers to contests with [swag](/questions/tagged/swag) as prices, [events](/questions/tagged/events) should be replaced by [contests](/questions/tagged/contests)
- "events" that refers to DevDays, [events](/questions/tagged/events) should be replaced by [devdays](/questions/tagged/devdays)