# An editing option for Chat Events/Room Schedules

Tags: feature-request, chat-event

[Creating chat events](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295936/what-are-chat-events-and-how-do-they-work) is one of those finest features available on SE Chatrooms. This can be created by a room owner of a chat room. I am looking  for **an editing option for chat events/room schedules** of a chatroom.

> Any room owner of a chat room can create an event on the Schedule tab of the room. Once you clicked "Add", the event is added to the Room Schedule, a message is posted in the room and the event is featured on the Main Chat page. From that moment on, users can register themselves for the event

Suppose you schedule an event for the chatroom and later, due to some reasons/issues, want to postpone that same event to some other date, you have to create a new event by removing the previous one, as currently there are no options existing/available for ROs for  editing it. All the users once registered for that particular event may automatically get "cancel registration" or removed from registration by this process.

Please make this option available for ROs along with the creation of chat events / room schedules.

Answer (score 6):

#### I support being able to edit the description

The creator or other RO being able to change the description/title of the event would be quite reasonable.

#### I'm against being able to edit the date/time while automatically keeping users registered

A user registering for an event represents their intent to be present at a specific date/time. It is not reasonable to assume that the user maintains that intent/commitment if the date/time changes. This isn't a work situation where the ROs get to dictate that users *will* show up at a rescheduled date/time. Without more tooling to explicitly inform users who have registered for the original event of a change in date/time and get their confirmation that they are still interested, it's better to *not* carry over users to a new date/time, which the system currently handles by forcing a new event to be created with no users automatically registered.

It would be reasonable to allow changing the event date/time, *if* the registered users were explicitly informed of the change and asked to confirm that they still intent to attend, but not to automatically register users for the changed date/time without their confirmation.

Overall, as currently written, I am against this proposal, as I don't feel it's appropriate to automatically keep users registered for a changed date/time. However, I would be in support of a change such that event date/time could be changed with registered users being directly notified of the changed date/time and given the option to re-register (default not registered).

Comment: I am against the support of make available an editing option for descriptions.Because, suppose one want to conduct a schedule of xyz topic, the users registered for that event would be interested in that xyz topic, so simply make available an editing option can completely change the xyz to a new event abc, without altering the date and time.But I am agreeing being able to edit date and time by "notifying" the registered users without removing them from the "postponed" event (i.e , the same xyz event).

Comment: @EasyFlow If you feel that altering the description is actually creating a new event, then it sounds like the current existing implementation is best, which forces a new event to be created to change any of description, date, or time, because I definitely feel that changing the date/time makes it a new event that should require a new commitment from the prospective attendees (*far* more so than a potentially minor change of description) (i.e. IMO, a date/time change is always major). Change notifications and required reconfirmation of each user's intent to attend would be reasonable, though.

Comment: I have posted my suggestions as an answer ,  as commenting is too broad.

Answer (score -2):

From @Makyen's suggestions and from the comments above, I would like to give my suggestion as an answer.

@Makyen's  support have two parts:

### Part (A): Being able to edit description/title

> #### I support being able to edit the description
>
> The creator or other RO being able to change the description/title of the event would be quite reasonable.

### Part (B): Being able to change date/time

> #### I'm against being able to edit the date/time while automatically keeping users registered:
>
> However, I would be in support of a change such that event date/time could be changed with registered users being directly notified of the changed date/time and given the option to re-register (default not registered).

From a comment:

> Without the implementing change notifications and required reconfirmation of intent to attend upon a change, and if you feel that altering the description is actually creating a new event, then it sounds like the current existing implementation is best, which forces a new event to be created with a new description, date, or time, because I definitely feel that changing the date/time makes it a new event that should require a new commitment from the prospective attendees (far more so than a potentially minor change of description) (i.e. IMO, a date/time change is always major).

I completely agree with the idea of "produce change notifications" when changing the name and time of an event. But I would like to add some more suggestions along with this.

### My Suggestions:

#### 1. From Part (A) and comment: Being able to edit description/title/topic

Make available an **editing option for the event description**: there should be sub options asking for *which/what purpose* you would like to make changes for the event description along with notifying the registered users.

As per the current system, editing title/description can be made in two cases:

- For a new schedule.
- For changing just the *description* of an existing event to a new one, to make it more attractive with the intention of getting attention, or also for some minor edits like grammar, punctuation etc.

For example:  Suppose I wish to schedule an event for the discussion of xyz topic under a description "The Binocular Vision". My intention of giving such an *event description* (which may pop up shortly before the start of the event and will seen by every user that is pingable in the room, that the event is about to start) would be as follows:

- i) A description that is connected to the event's topic/purpose
- ii) A description that is capable of attracting users who might be interested in that particular event topic/purpose.

(Note: currently there no separate options exist for giving a title and adding a description of the purpose of the event)

So in this case, a sub option asking for the purpose of changing event description would be a great idea. Like an editing option as below (editing purpose for event description only):

[image: Under a header "Edit event description" are two radio buttons, one for "For new schedule" and one for "For new name". The current description and topic are displayed, as are "Save" and "Cancel" buttons.]

Activate both the "Topic" and "Description" icons only for option (1). Notifications of the change have to be made in this case only. For each edit, a message has to be posted in the chatroom as well.

Demerits: But if the editing option is only made available for changing event description like as above, there are no other options for changing date/time for icon "For new schedule".

#### 2. From Part (B) and the comment: Being able to change date/time

The changes in date and time of a schedule can be made in two situations, i.e.:

- If planning to conduct a completely *new schedule*.
- To *postpone* a fixed event due to some reasons/issues or for some minor mistake edits.

In this case, **an editing option for date and time** has to be made available along with producing change notifications to the users (registered) by considering these two situations, like as below (a sample):

[image: Under a header "Edit event Date and Time" are four radio buttons: "For new schedule", "time only", "date only", and "date and time". The current time and date are displayed, as are "Save" and "Cancel" buttons.]

Activate both "Time" and "Date" icons only for options (1) and (4). A *notification of the change* has to be made in 1st case. For each edit, a message has to be posted in the chatroom as well.

Demerits: But if editing option is only make available for changing time and date like as above, there are no other options available for changing description and topic/purpose for icon "For new schedule".

#### My Conclusion:

Overall, I am pointing out the necessity of an editing option for chat events whether or not there are users registered for that particular event. But in the current system, one have to create new event each time for those edits which I have mentioned above.

By considering the *demerits* from my suggestions (1) and (2), I would like to conclude — make editing option available like as below (a sample):

[image: Under a header "Edit Room Schedule" are two checkboxes, one for "Edit event Description" and one for "Edit event Date and time". Each has radio buttons like in the previous pictures. The current description, topic, time, and date are displayed, as are "Save" and "Cancel" buttons.]

An editing option combining both time/date and description.